# interpretation of a lemma

Tags: functional-analysis

In this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584880406), chapter $2$, lemma $2.2.2$, states the following:

> Suppose $K$ is a countably compact space with $f,g \in C(K)$ and $\|f\| \leq 1$ and $\|g\| \leq 1$. Then $f \in st(g)$ if and only if there exists $t_0\in K$ such that $f(t_0)=g(t_0)$ and $|f(t_0)|=|g(t_0)|=1$

$C(K)$ is the space which contains all real continuous functions defined on $K$ and $st(g)=\{ f \in C(K): \|f\|=1,\|f+g\|=2 \}$

My interpretation of this lemma is: All elements in the set $st(g)$ attains maximum value at the same point as $g$.

Is my interpretation correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation (or at least my interpretation of your interpretation) isn't quite correct. In part it is stronger, in part weaker than what the lemma really asserts.

On the one hand, $\lvert g\rvert$ can attain its maximum in more than one point, and an $f \in st(g)$ need not attain its maximum modulus in all points where $\lvert g\rvert$ attains its maximum, and $f\in st(g)$ can attain its maximum modulus also in points where $\lvert g\rvert$ doesn't. So

> attains maximum value at the same point as $g$.

seems (to me) to assert a bit more than what is actually the case.

But, part of what the lemma asserts is indeed that there is at least one point $t_0$ where both, $\lvert g\rvert$ and $\lvert f\rvert$ attain their respective maximum.

Further the lemma asserts that in at least one of the points where $\lvert g\rvert$ and $\lvert f\rvert$ both attain their maximum, actually both $g$ and $f$ have the same value.